# how to auto login using js

Tags: javascript, authentication

I would like to make auto login on my web site tto as I login in my android app. Mostly, this web will be shown on android. So I want to make my user easy to login when they use my web site.

Right now, I can see only login with javascript on facebook developer page. For it, we need to type user's id and password.

I wonder that is there any way to get login information from their local facebook application to auto login on my website using javascript if they are not logged in on web.

Thank you to read this. Have a nice day :)

Comment: i am sorry i submit the wrong content!!  there is what i wanto ask    i need to login to a website everyday, 
now i want to using js to auto login in to this website.

there is what i do everyday.
1.input the username in first webpage and submit
2.the page will jump to the next page where i need to input my password 
and then submit
3.the page will jump to the confirm page where i need to submit once again.

i want to write the js to instead of my hand working, if i can get the source that will be very nice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the user's sign in credentials from Facebook?  If so, no there isn't, but Facebook does support a use case for using them as the authentication provider.  It isn't a simple javascript file though, you have to implement it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.3